# Error: jQuery jquery.min.js?_=1420285687057:4 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, html5-history

I have problem with jquery validate plugn and history API, when i click few times
i have error jquery.min.js?_=1420288991396:4 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function, when I comment a fragment with validate, script works fine. How concat this script.
In file script.js i have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#loginForm").validate({
            rules: {
                username: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
            },
            messages: {
                username: {
                    required: "Please enter a username",
                    minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
                },
                password: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                },
            },

            submitHandler: function() {
                var username=$("#usernameLogin").val();
                var password=$("#passwordLogin").val();
                var dataString = 'username='+username+'&password='+password+'&tag=login';
                if($.trim(username).length>0 && $.trim(password).length>0){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "include/help4meApi.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data){
                            if(data){       
                                if($("#rememberMe:checked").val()){
                                    checkCookie(username);
                                }
                                window.location.href = "index.php";
                            }
                            else{   
                                $("#error").html("<label class='error'>Wrong password or username!</label>");
                                console.log("Wrong password or username!");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        // validate signup form on keyup and submit
        $("#signupForm").validate({
            rules: {
                firstname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3
                },
                lastname: "required",
                username: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                confirm_password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    equalTo: "#password"
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                firstname: {
                    required: "Please enter your firstname",
                    minlength: "Your firstname  must consist of at least 3 characters"
                },
                lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
                username: {
                    required: "Please enter a username",
                    minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
                },
                password: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                },
                confirm_password: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                    equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
                },
                email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            },

            submitHandler: function() {
                var username=$("#username").val();
                var password=$("#password").val();
                var firstname=$("#firstname").val();
                var lastname=$("#lastname").val();
                var email=$("#email").val();
                var dataString = 'username='+username+'&password='+password+'&firstname='+firstname+'&lastname='+lastname+'&email='+email+'&tag=register';
                if($.trim(username).length>0 && $.trim(password).length>0){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "include/help4meApi.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data){
                            if(data){
                                console.log(data);
                                $(".register_notification").html("<label class='error' style='background:#6DC066'>Register successfully!</label>");
                            }
                            else{   
                                $(".register_notification").html("<label class='error'>Username already exists, please choose another one!</label>");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        // propose username by combining first- and lastname
        $("#username").focus(function() {
            var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
            var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
            if (firstname && lastname && !this.value) {
                this.value = firstname + "." + lastname;
            }
        });

    $("footer a").click(function(e){
        //e.preventDefault(); 
        /*  
        if uncomment the above line, html5 nonsupported browers won't change the url but will display the ajax content;
        if commented, html5 nonsupported browers will reload the page to the specified link. 
        */

        //get the link location that was clicked
        pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
        //to get the ajax content and display in div with id 'content'
        $.ajax({url:pageurl,success: function(data){
            $('#login_box').html(data);
        }});

        //to change the browser URL to 'pageurl'
        if(pageurl!=window.location){
            window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);    
        }
        return false;  
    });
 });


$(window).bind('popstate', function() {
    if(!location.pathname.localeCompare('/login.php')){
        $.ajax({url:location.pathname,success: function(data){
            $('body').html(data);
        }});
    }
    else{
        $.ajax({url:location.pathname,success: function(data){
            $('#login_box').html(data);
        }});
    }

});
```

From jQuery library:

```
// Get transport
transport = inspectPrefiltersOrTransports( transports, s, options, jqXHR );

// If no transport, we auto-abort
if ( !transport ) {
    done( -1, "No Transport" );
} else {
    jqXHR.readyState = 1;

    // Send global event
    if ( fireGlobals ) {
        globalEventContext.trigger( "ajaxSend", [ jqXHR, s ] );
    }
    // Timeout
    if ( s.async && s.timeout > 0 ) {
        timeoutTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            jqXHR.abort("timeout");
        }, s.timeout );
    }

    try {
        state = 1;
        transport.send( requestHeaders, done );
    } catch ( e ) {
        // Propagate exception as error if not done
        if ( state < 2 ) {
            done( -1, e );
        // Simply rethrow otherwise
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

it shows throw e.

Comment: Are you sure all this code is needed to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which line throws the error?

Comment: @Vohuman that is the problem, line number is: jquery.min.js?_=1420288991396:4

Comment: Why are you developing with a minified library without a source map?

Comment: @Vohuman, go on  http://help4me.pl/login.php click on Kontakt link and click backspace, do this once again and if you look at the console you have a error

Comment: As _jQuery_  is minified the linenumber is not useful. Even with a not minified version of jQuery we would most likely only be able to tell you that you call a function on an either empty jQuery result set or on a result set that contains an invalid item. You would need to to use the stack trace to find out the origin of the problem in your code.

Comment: I suggest that you use [the CDN links provided by the developer](http://jqueryvalidation.org/#1-13-1-files-on-microsoft-s-ajax-cdn-(hotlinking-welcome):) instead of leaching off the version used on his domain.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any reason why using the browser's "back" button would cause the JavaScript to fail.  Everything should be cached and continue to work as before.

The error you're getting is similar to the error you'd get if you failed to include the plugin.

Here is how you're including the jQuery Validate plugin...

```
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Notice how you're hotlinking to the plugin hosted on the developer's own domain. (*likely for his demos and/or to download*.)  This error might be caused by a timing issue, the plugin not loading fast enough from this URL.

The developer has provided his plugin on two different free CDN services where *"hotlinking welcome"*.  So instead of leaching the plugin directly from his domain, try hotlinking to the CDN links provided [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/#1-13-1-files-on-microsoft-s-ajax-cdn-(hotlinking-welcome):).

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```